# How do I resolve this ambiguous type error in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

So I created a new Xcode project, and wrote this `Podfile`:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'Repro' do
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Result'
end
```

Then I ran `pod install`, opened up the workspace, and created a new file with the following contents:

```
import Alamofire
import Result

private func something(request: Request) -> Result<Bool, NSError> {
    fatalError()
}
```

And I tried to build this, but Xcode produced the error `'Result' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`. So I tried the obvious fix:

```
import Alamofire
import Result

private func something(request: Request) -> Result.Result<Bool, NSError> {
    fatalError()
}
```

But that gave me the error `Reference to generic type 'Result' requires arguments in <...>`, as if Swift were parsing the module name as the type name.

What's the non-obvious fix?

Comment: @dfri This is as stripped-down an example as I can concoct; as such I'm using `fatalError` as a way to omit the body of the function without affecting the ability of the program typecheck. Substitute `return .Success(true)`, or whatever else -- the body doesn't affect Swift's ability to process the type signature.

Comment: I see, didn't know `fatalError` could be used in such a neat fashion, thanks for that!

Comment: AlamoFire also defines a `Result` type so it doest know which one to use.

Comment: @CleverError Yes. That is the problem. But how do you indicate which one to use?

Comment: have you tried restarting your computer ian

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you directly import the Result module's `Result` type, it'll override Alamofire's `Result` type. You can still reach Alamofire's using its qualified name:

```
import Alamofire
import enum Result.Result

let a: Alamofire.Result<T, ErrorType> // Alamofire's Result
let r: Result<T, ErrorType> // Result module's Result
```

I found this out through trial and error after seeing [detailed import mentioned in the language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID354). I don't know if type name resolution is documented anywhere as working this way, so it might change without much notice.

Comment: How do I use the namespace for `Result.Result`?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz I'm not sure you can access the `Result` module when there's already a type in scope called `Result`. You can get to the `Result.Result` type as seen in my example. If there are other types in the `Result` module that you want to use, you'll have to `import enum Result.OtherResult` or equivalent. Does that make sense?

I believe https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-898 is the bug to track here.

Comment: The problem is that I already have another `Result` structure, so I can't use the `Result.Result` as `Result`.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz can you access your other `Result` struct as `YourModuleName.Result`? Or can you use `typealias` here somehow? Otherwise without seeing code I'm kinda out of suggestions, sorry :/

Comment: I can, but I don't want to, I want to access the Moya Result as `Result.Result`, or something similar. It also creates other conflicts just by having the `Result` structure in the project.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that the [Result](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Result/1.0.1/) *cocoapod* is out of style with swift 2.1, and may be obviated with the language updates - they should be doing something more like

```
private func something(request: Request) throws -> Result {
  // TODO: implement this 
  throw RequestError()
}
```

which removes the need for the wrapping of return value.

---

I would have used a *tuple* in the first place `(Bool, NSError)` instead of a custom enum. But that's stylistic.

Comment: I think you should post this as a comment rather than an answer, as it doesn't address the actual problem of modules-with-the-same-names-as-types-breaking-the-Swift-parser. I know that I presented a very minimal code example, but the reality is not as simple as "don't do that." (Specifically, I'm interacting with another third party library which itself expects the `Result` type, and I can't just pass it a tuple). Also, tuples are not isomorphic to enums -- [products ≠ sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Comment: I did consider doing that, and agree with the sentiment, but the formatting issues led to this choice.

Comment: I think you should rethink what you're thinking =), `throw`'s should be abolished forever, just look into functional programming and you'll understand why.